# Bash Script Until condition to listen the specific port should run

Tags: bash

I have two shell script in two different machines, first shell script (util.sh) this script contains until condition to perform certain action in another server called host-2, myscript.sh need complete their task to listen port 8878.

When the 8878 port is up and running then i need resume my script (util.sh) from host-1.

```
#!/bin/bash

until cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/host-2/8878; do
           echo waiting
              sleep 10m
      done
      ./myscript.sh
```

host-1

```
#!/bin/bash

command1
command2
command3
```

Comment: ok but what is your question?

Comment: i want to listen the port number from the remote server